# gpg keyserver receive failed No name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, runtime-error, gnupg, keyserver

I am seting up a docker container
When it reaches to set environment, it shows error upon processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10)
And throws the folowing error:

`gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created`

`gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created`

`gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name`

Comment: Most likely related to https://sks-keyservers.net being deprecated